# Azure oozie workflow

Tags: azure, hadoop, sqoop, oozie, azure-hdinsight

i am trying to run a oozie workflow on azurehdinsight cluster the job definition looks like this:

```
<workflow-app xmlns="uri:oozie:workflow:0.2" name="oozie-sqoop">
  <start to="sqoop1" />
  <action name="sqoop1">
    <sqoop xmlns="uri:oozie:sqoop-action:0.4">
      <job-tracker>jobtrackerhost:9010</job-tracker>
      <name-node>wasb://abc@def.blob.core.windows.net</name-node>
      <configuration>
        <property>
          <name>mapred.job.queue.name</name>
          <value>default</value>
        </property>
      </configuration>
      <arg>import</arg>
      <arg>--connect</arg>
      <arg>jdbc:mysql://{ip}/svnadmin</arg>
      <arg>--username</arg>
      <arg>uname</arg>
      <arg>--password</arg>
      <arg>password</arg>
      <arg>--table</arg>
      <arg>rights</arg>
      <arg>--hive-import</arg>
    </sqoop>
    <ok to="end" />
    <error to="fail" />
  </action>
  <kill name="fail">
    <message>sqoop failed, error message[${wf:errorMessage(wf:lastErrorNode())}]</message>
  </kill>
  <end name="end" />
</workflow-app>
```

log:

```
2016-10-04 06:16:06,816  INFO ActionStartXCommand:520 - SERVER[hn0-saint.3oitbdwtly0uzabcmledackovts0a.bx.internal.cloudapp.net] USER[saint] GROUP[-] TOKEN[] APP[oozie-sqoop] JOB[0000015-160928235712742-oozie-oozi-W] ACTION[0000015-160928235712742-oozie-oozi-W@:start:] Start action [0000015-160928235712742-oozie-oozi-W@:start:] with user-retry state : userRetryCount [0], userRetryMax [0], userRetryInterval [10]
2016-10-04 06:16:06,827  INFO ActionStartXCommand:520 - SERVER[hn0-saint.3oitbdwtly0uzmledackovts0a.bx.internal.cloudapp.net] USER[saint] GROUP[-] TOKEN[] APP[oozie-sqoop] JOB[0000015-160928235712742-oozie-oozi-W] ACTION[0000015-160928235712742-oozie-oozi-W@:start:] [***0000015-160928235712742-oozie-oozi-W@:start:***]Action status=DONE
2016-10-04 06:16:06,828  INFO ActionStartXCommand:520 - SERVER[hn0-saint.3oitbdwtly0uzmleklasackovts0a.bx.internal.cloudapp.net] USER[saint] GROUP[-] TOKEN[] APP[oozie-sqoop] JOB[0000015-160928235712742-oozie-oozi-W] ACTION[0000015-160928235712742-oozie-oozi-W@:start:] [***0000015-160928235712742-oozie-oozi-W@:start:***]Action updated in DB!
2016-10-04 06:16:07,508  INFO WorkflowNotificationXCommand:520 - SERVER[hn0-saint.3oitbdxbtly0uzmledackovts0a.bx.internal.cloudapp.net] USER[-] GROUP[-] TOKEN[-] APP[-] JOB[0000015-160928235712742-oozie-oozi-W] ACTION[] No Notification URL is defined. Therefore nothing to notify for job 0000015-160928235712742-oozie-oozi-W
```

but it is not importing anything to hive . When i tried the same with sqoop command  it succeeded and successfully imported to hive.
it always showing status as running and it never change to anything

Comment: Can you take a look into this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27740936/oozie-sqoop-action-with-hive-import

Comment: I appreciate your effort and time to answer this question. in that post all the values ; i mean jobtracker url and all replaced by expressions ; in my case i strongly believe that some thing wrong in the job tracker url or may be in name-node . i have tested the same job with cloudera and it works;

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your WASB path is wrong , not sure if you changed it for posting purpose.

I believe it should be as below.

```
<name-node>wasbs://abc@def.blob.core.windows.net</name-node>
```

You are missing **s** , please check.